# NSScrollView with corePlot let NSScrollView to handle scrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-plot, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollView` and some (dynamic) plots inside it 
I have made plots using `corePlot` frameworks .

When I want to scroll the `NSScrollView` while my mouse is not on 1 of the plots everything works fine , however when I scrolling and my mouse is pointed on 1 of the plots nothing happens . I assume it happens because corePlot eats the scrolling events.

I have set `allowUserInteractions` to `NO` , but it didn't solve the problem .

My question is : How can I "transfer"(don't know what word better suits here) the scrolling events from the plot to the `NSScrollView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue however not perfect solution but fast and reliable (cons: 1.eats ram 2.required library)

I put `RMBluredView` on top of my `NSScrolView` on top of the graph plots
and added the method in to `RMBluredView` to override the scrolling events and pass them to the super.

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event 
{
    [super scrollWheel:event];
    [[self nextResponder]scrollWheel:event];
}
```

Perhaps there is better solutions ,however I don't feel like spending whole day or even more inside the `corePlot` libraries and finding who eating my precious scrolling events ;)

So if someone will stuck with the same problem I hope it will be useful :)

Comment: The Core Plot hosting view is eating the events. Please report this on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues) and we'll fix it.

Comment: I have to be signed in to gitHub but I have no account there.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the issue for you.

Comment: @EricSkroch Thanks :) , and Huge thanks for CorePlot (I guess u r involved in it:) ).